# How To Take Full Snapshot Of UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage, uitextview

I'm trying to take snapshot of `UITextView` using below code

```
extension UIView {

    func pb_takeSnapshot() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        drawHierarchy(in: self.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

But I gives me half snapshot. Even `UITextView` and `Snapshot` image has same `width` and `height` when i check using `print`. I also tried different codes but not worked. Can anyone tell me how i can fix it, i want full snapshot of `UITextView`.

This is my `UITextView` With `Frame` (0.0, 97.0, 414.0, 234.0)
[image]

And this is snapshot image using `pb_takeSnapshot()` With `Frame` width = 414.0, height = 234.0
[image] .

Comment: change the drawHierarchy call to ` drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)` , i reckon you need to draw it in bounds

Comment: @FruitAddict i tried but now it gives me image like [that](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j_T52ZT90DH1f2shHz2S70BWSFxzIM-b/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Can you print self.bounds and see what values you're getting for x and y (after you've changed drawHierarchy to use self.bounds instead of self.frame)? The bounds should be (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 234.0).

Comment: @PeteMorris I print `self.bounds` after `drawHierarchy.....` and it gives me that result `self.bounds (0.0, -94.0, 414.0, 234.0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the `frame` to do the drawing (and for some reason, as you said in the comments) your `bounds` are not giving the correct value.

It would be hard to debug the reason for that without looking at your view hierarchy, however you should still be able create a correct snapshot.

Create the rect to draw in from scratch instead:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
drawHierarchy(in: rect, afterScreenUpdates: true)
```